# How to say 'we will work in future' with a positive attitiude

Tags: software-industry, communication, work-environment

I work in an IT company, I was working on a project, let say A and later I was moved to another project, let say B.

Now the architect with whom I was working on project A wants me back to work on the project.
However, to resource allocation constraint I can't be allocated back to project A.

So now my question is how can I say to my architect with a kind gesture that I would come back and work in the future with a positive note?

Comment: What is your position? Do you choose where you work?

Comment: I am a Software developer. No, I can't choose where to work

Comment: Then it's not up to you, if he asks, politely give him the contact details of the person who assigns you.

Answer (score 5):

As you do not decide where you work, you an just say the same. I'm a bit surprised that the architect does not know that already, or if they know, why'd they ask you.

When next time you meet them, mention that

> *"It's very kind of you to think about me as part of your team, but as you might be knowing, I'm not the one making that decision. You can talk to X about this" (if you know whom to contact - your line manager / resource manager), or, "I guess you know people who can make these decisions. As from my side, I'm okay to work with you, but as I was told, they cannot move me back due to lack of resource in current assignment. Let me know what you decide"*.

And leave at that. let them figure out the rest.

Answer (score 2):

Tell him that you appreciate the professional equation you have had with him, but due to resource allocation shortage you will have to contribute to project B for some time. And would like to get back working together and making things happen.

Ask to meet him on coffee break, don't text him this. Meeting face to face symbolises personal touch and care vis a vis text/email.

Answer (score 0):

Often it can be useful to steer a conversation in a slightly different direction. For instance, in such cases you can interpret this as a compliment. "Thank you. I really enjoyed working on project A, and it's good to hear that I'm still welcome. I will let my manager know."

In other words, you take it as a compliment, and return a compliment. Then you let the architect know that you can't decide yourself to return, and that there's a manager involved. You avoid negative words like "can't", "but", etcetera. There's nothing bad here, so don't make it appear bad.